# How do I enable recuring donations when I have two payment processors enabled, one which supports recuring donations and one that does not?

Tags: wordpress, contributions, stripe

I am using WP Version 5.7.2 and CiviCRM V 5.37.0. The two payment processors are Stripe and BTCPay.

BTCPay obviously does not support recurring payments (not really a thing with cryptocurrency atm) but Stripe does. So when someone pays with Stripe, there should be an option for them to make recurring payments.

But every time I try to enable BTCPay as a payment processor, the recurring payment option checkbox disappears.

Video shows the problem: https://watch.rt4mn.org/videos/watch/f255ffe2-71b8-48d9-acf4-1bac95aeb90e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this on the same contribution page (at least not without custom code). If one of the enabled processors does not support recurring contributions the option will not be available on the entire contribution page.

The solution normally used is to have two separate contribution pages.

Comment: This is frustrating, as every additional click leads to a drop off of engagement.

Is there a way to have different contribution pages go towards the same progress bar widget?

Comment: I'm in agreement, there should maybe be a way to choose the the payment method first and than see the rest after so recurring will only be an option if a supporting payment method is chosen.