# Two contribution pages on the same page? (or a way to work around limitatin on recuring contributions)

Tags: wordpress, contributions, recurring-contributions, stripe

I am using WP Version 5.7.2 and CiviCRM V 5.37.0.

I would like to give potential doners a single donation page with the choice between using stripe or donating with crypto. [But the option to enable recurring donations is removed if one of the payment processors does not support recurring donations](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39680/how-do-i-enable-recuring-donations-when-i-have-two-payment-processors-enabled-o) so I would need to setup two different donation pages.

sadly having separate pages is not a real option for our org. Promoting financial privacy is a big part of what we do, so I can't relegate crypto payments to a second class status requiring additional clickthroughs, and I don't want to have to manually update the donation widget either.

But I also know recurring CC donations are incredibly important for long term growth, so I need an option that would enable recurring donations on the main donation page as well.

Is there a way I can have one donation page, one widget, one form, that gives users the options to choose between setting up a recurring donation with stripe, making a one time donation with stripe, or making a one time donation with btcpay, without me having to write custom code? I tried using shortcodes, but when you have two donation pages on the same page using short codes it just collapses the forms down, and people have to click through to another page.