# Fooling civicrm into thinking payment processor supports recurring donatoins

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

I am using WP Version 5.7.2 and CiviCRM V 5.37.0. The two payment processors are Stripe and BTCPay.

Frustratingly, If you have two payment processors and one of them does not support recurring contributions the option will not be available on the entire contribution page. [How do I enable recuring donations when I have two payment processors enabled, one which supports recuring donations and one that does not?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39680/how-do-i-enable-recuring-donations-when-i-have-two-payment-processors-enabled-o)

Is there a way to lie to civicrm to tell it that the second plugin accepts recurring contributions? I tried editing `is_recur` settings of this file to 1 but that did not work https://github.com/rukykf/btcpay/blob/master/btcpay.mgd.php

Having two payment pages is not a real option, promoting financial privacy is a big part of what we do, so I can't relegate crypto payments to a second class status requiring additional clickthroughs, and I don't want to have to manually update the donation widget either.

Comment: I would look at a 3rd party webform for your contribution page. I do not know what is available for WP. Drupal has Webform CiviCRM integration available. With this you could create a webform for your contribution page that has the Civi/payment processor(s) baked into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you did manage to fool civicrm into thinking your second payment processor can accept recurring contributions, that sounds like a bad thing?

Your method looks like it should work, but you might need some aggressive cache clearing (eg. by enabling/disabling some other extension).

Handling mixes of processors with different capabilities is a tough issue.

Comment: simply editing the is_recur option does not seem to work, could you elaborate on what you mean by cache clearing?

Comment: Chances are for most payment processors, the payment processor configuration is in a managed record, so you wouldn't be able to override it via the command line. By aggressive cache clearing, I mean that a lot of civicrm configuration gets stored in a cache, some of which may not get cleared unless you enable/disable an extension (any extension, but don't break your site!).